# Wifi issues in Ubuntu 20.04.6LTS

Tags: networking, drivers, dual-boot, internet

I have dual booted windows 7 and Ubuntu 20.04.6LTS. I have a wifi dongle which is Digisol DN-WN3300N. On windows 7, I have a realtek lan utility to connect to the internet, and lights blink on the dongle. But on ubuntu, there is no blinking lights on the dongle, there is wifi enabled, there are visible wifi networks, but when i am trying to connect to anything, its saying "activation of network connection failed" (Not connecting to my phone hotspot too). I have tried everything on the internet which I dont even remember and got "There is no wifi adapter", so i reinstalled Ubuntu now. As of now, I did

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

lsusb:

```
    Bus 001 Device 012: ID 05c6:9024 Qualcomm, Inc. SAMSUNG_Android
    Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:818b Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8192EU 802.11b/g/n WLAN Adapter
    Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    Bus 005 Device 002: ID 2a7a:9a18 CASUE CASUE USB Keyboard
    Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
    Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
    Bus 003 Device 002: ID 1c4f:0034 SiGma Micro Usb Mouse
    Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
    Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 82945G/GZ/P/PL Memory Controller Hub (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 82945G/GZ Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 01)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 1 (rev 01)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 01)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 01)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 01)
00:1d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 01)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 01)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev e1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801GB/GR (ICH7 Family) LPC Interface Bridge (rev 01)
00:1f.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801G (ICH7 Family) IDE Controller (rev 01)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family SATA Controller [IDE mode] (rev 01)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family SMBus Controller (rev 01)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 01)
```

iwconfig:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp1s0    no wireless extensions.

wlx00177c8fa9a5  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          
usb0      no wireless extensions.
```

Wifi Diagnostic script: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/GHWw7YtTgh/

Please Help

Comment: Please post the output of this [wifi diagnostic script](https://askubuntu.com/a/425180). Also, Windows 7 should not be connected to the internet. Please stop doing that

Comment: I entered that command but it's not connecting, it's saying "connectiion timed out" and "Network is unreachable", I will try this command again later. About the windows 7, there is no way my pc can run modern windows, so I had to..

Comment: I have posted the script output in the question. Thanks for the directions so far..